# tar and recursive archiving

Tags: bash, recursion, find, tar

My code below supposed to look for folders recursively which contain doc/docx files and archive only those in their path. When find in tar gives empty. tar breaks with Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive. I use -maxdepth 1 to avoid it but not sure if this is correct solution. Another problem is oring doesn't work as expected. If *notest* exists then *test* will be ignored. Any suggestions?
Also feel free to suggest some code optimization

```
for D in $(find . ! -newermt $date1 -ipath "*test*" -or -ipath "*notest*" -iregex ".*\.\(doc\|docx\)" -printf "%h\n" | sort -u)
    do :
    cd $D && tar --no-recursion --ignore-failed-read -czf archive.tar.zip $(find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.doc" -or -iname "*.docx" ) --remove-files
    cd ~
done
```

Example

```
Test
  |____ test
  |       |___ subtest ___ 1.doc
  |                   |___ 2.doc
  |                   |___ 3.pdf
  |____ notest ___ 1.doc
              |___ 2.docx
```

Expected

```
Test
  |___ test
  |      |___ subtest ___ archive.tar.zip (contains docs)
  |                  |___ 3.pdf
  |___ notest ___ archive.tar.zip (contains docs)
```

Comment: Note that `.zip` indicates a particular type of archive which you can manipulate with [zip](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zip&manpath=FreeBSD+Ports+9.2-RELEASE) and [unzip](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unzip&manpath=FreeBSD+Ports+9.2-RELEASE).  For a gzipped tar, it's customary to end the filename in `.tar.gz`.

Comment: This is the idea, because this is a Cloud Storage and can be opened by different stations running different OS. So don't want to restrict users with tools.

Comment: Changing the name of the file doesn't change the format of the file.  If you want to create a zip archive, you have to use a tool that can do that.  Tar is likely not that tool.  If you want something that works the same way across almost all unix-like systems, `.tar.gz` is likely the way to go.  If you want compatibility with Windows, ZIP may be a better option.  Either way, you need the right tool for the job.

Comment: True story. You are definitely right but this is not the whole code to tell the truth. It's part of a code that do all the archiving and backup automatically. This is a summary of the logic but the compression tool used is `.zip`. My bad I didn't make it clear before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next:

```
arch="archive.tar.gz"
while read -r -d $'\0' dir
do
    (cd "$dir" && find . -maxdepth 1 -iregex '.*\.docx?' -print0 | tar --null -czf "$arch" -T - --remove-files)
    #alternatively
    #(cd "$dir" && shopt -s nocaseglob nullglob && tar --no-recursion -czf "$arch" *.doc *.docx  --remove-files)
done < <(find . \( -ipath '*/test/*' -o -ipath '*/notest/*' \) -iregex '.*\.docx?' -printf '%h\0' | sort -zu)
```

some comments:

- alternative `-ipath` with the construction `\( -ipath '*/test/*' -o -ipath '*/notest/*' \)`
- the regex `.*\.docx?` - must match the whole filename and the `x?` mean *zero or one `x`*
- tar can read the list of files from stdin with `-T -`
- using null terminated filenames (helps if paths contain spaces)
- the `--null` instructs tar to use such null terminated filenames
- `(cd ... &&)` run in the subshell, so not need `cd` back

Comment: I used partly what you suggested and it gave better results. Thanks

Comment: @Odin no problem. ANyway, for me gave exactly what you wanted - if you have some problems, edit your question...

Comment: How can I also use `-iregex` with `-ipath`. For example `\( -ipath -iregex ".*\.\(test\|notest\) \)"`?